# Formatting of "Release Notes" window

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, update-manager

I was trying to upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 following [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/upgrade). If you take a look at the image from **step 3**:

[image]

The content inside the **Release Notes** window is formatted correctly. Now, this is my **Release Notes** window after I click the **Upgrade** button:

[image]

As you can see, the content is not being formatted at all.

How can I solve this?

Comment: When I load the 11.04 amd64 live cd with active internet connection, I wait a bit and it shows an "Ubuntu 11.10 upgrade available" window which gets parsed correctly: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pFbUR.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround:

Run:

```
gconf-editor /apps/update-manager
```

Clear the value in key "check_new_release_ignore"

Run:

```
killall -r check-new-release-gtk
/usr/lib/update-manager/check-new-release-gtk
```

Result: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/860rg.png]

The update-manager window is probably missing the show_uri (webkit.webview). Looking at update-manager on 11.10, it has a DistUpgradeFetcher.py (showReleaseNotes) that falls back to text for *some reason* (maybe something in ReleaseNotesViewer.py ?).

Please file a bug report about it:

```
ubuntu-bug update-manager
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, to be honest on your own you cannot solve this unless you are a coder and willing to submit a patch against the code for the update manager ;).

That happens because the two windows you see are using different methods for rendering the text, and this can only be fixed at the code level (not by simply tweaking some setting).